# Pass arguments on WinJS.Navigation

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am working on Windows 8 Metro App using Javascript. I want to pass arguments from screen 1 to screen 2.

I am navigating in this way.
Screen-1

var nav = WinJS.Navigation;

```
function navigate(){
    nav.navigate("someurl.html", "Pass Argument");
}

Screen-2
I want to access that argument at  

ready: function (element, options){
    "Access Argument"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the [WinJS.Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229778.aspx) namespace, you should be able to get the parameter passed in via `WinJS.Navigation.state`

```
ready: function (element, options){
    var myArg = WinJS.Navigation.state;
}
```